# div aligning content to other div

Tags: html, css

On my website i have the following layout:

```
outer-div with display: table
inner-div with display: table-row and width/height 100%
list-div with display: table-cell and width 25%
detail-div with display: table-cell and height 75%
```

Inside the list-div there is a ul with a few li elements. In the detail-div there is another div with width/height 100%. Here is an image how it looks at the beginning:
http://puu.sh/5e1wo.png

Notice the top margin of the list elements. When i click on one of the projects the idea is to add its (html-)description inside the detail-div element. While it works it oddly also affects the margin of the list-elements as you can see in the next pictures: http://puu.sh/5e1HI.png
http://puu.sh/5e1Iq.png

It somehow seems like the list elements are aligned to the content in the other div even if their first common anchestor is like 3 levels above. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Open next inline-element using webkit-triads and then cross-ckeck the view with what u want. it works with chrome. do u have chrome or not?

Comment: Yes, I use chrome, but im not sure what you mean by webkit-triads.

Comment: do u have deep knowledge in webkit engine and how it renders webpage?

Comment: No, i wouldnt say that.